# Getting the same attributes for every member (what is not desired)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am creating several static global instances. Here is the global class:

```
public static class global_instances {

    public static Orders order1 = new Orders ();
    public static Orders order2 = new Orders ();
    public static Orders order3 = new Orders ();
    public static Orders order4 = new Orders ();
    public static Orders order5 = new Orders ();
    public static Orders order6 = new Orders ();
}
```

The Orders class contains several fields, like id, name, and so on.

I am using the mysql reader to fill these object-fields with unique attributes.

Here is the problem: Every static member of the object is having the same attribute after assigning them, exactly the last data-record. But every record should be unique, like in my database. Here is the assignment class:

```
internal static class Assignments
{
    private static Queue<int> assign_ids = new Queue<int>();

    internal static void orders()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i)
        {
            assign_ids.Enqueue(i);
        }

        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection sql_connection = null;
        sql_connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user id=root; password=123; database=tables; persist security info=False");

        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand sql_command = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();

        sql_command.Connection = sql_connection;

        sql_connection.Open();
        string id_string = Convert.ToString(assign_ids.Peek());
        sql_command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id='" + id_string + "';";
        var sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i)
        {
            id_string = Convert.ToString(assign_ids.Peek());
            sql_command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id='" + id_string + "';"; assign_ids.Dequeue();
            while (sql_reader.Read())
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1: global_instances.order1.modify(sql_reader.GetString(0), sql_reader.GetString(1), sql_reader.GetUInt16(2), sql_reader.GetString(3), sql_reader.GetString(4), sql_reader.GetString(5), sql_reader.GetInt16(6), sql_reader.GetInt16(7), sql_reader.GetString(8), sql_reader.GetString(9));
                        break;
                    case 2: global_instances.order2.modify(sql_reader.GetString(0), sql_reader.GetString(1), sql_reader.GetUInt16(2), sql_reader.GetString(3), sql_reader.GetString(4), sql_reader.GetString(5), sql_reader.GetInt16(6), sql_reader.GetInt16(7), sql_reader.GetString(8), sql_reader.GetString(9));
                        break;
                    case 3: global_instances.order3.modify(sql_reader.GetString(0), sql_reader.GetString(1), sql_reader.GetUInt16(2), sql_reader.GetString(3), sql_reader.GetString(4), sql_reader.GetString(5), sql_reader.GetInt16(6), sql_reader.GetInt16(7), sql_reader.GetString(8), sql_reader.GetString(9));
                        break;
                    case 4: global_instances.order4.modify(sql_reader.GetString(0), sql_reader.GetString(1), sql_reader.GetUInt16(2), sql_reader.GetString(3), sql_reader.GetString(4), sql_reader.GetString(5), sql_reader.GetInt16(6), sql_reader.GetInt16(7), sql_reader.GetString(8), sql_reader.GetString(9));
                        break;
                    case 5: global_instances.order5.modify(sql_reader.GetString(0), sql_reader.GetString(1), sql_reader.GetUInt16(2), sql_reader.GetString(3), sql_reader.GetString(4), sql_reader.GetString(5), sql_reader.GetInt16(6), sql_reader.GetInt16(7), sql_reader.GetString(8), sql_reader.GetString(9));
                        break;
                    case 6: global_instances.order6.modify(sql_reader.GetString(0), sql_reader.GetString(1), sql_reader.GetUInt16(2), sql_reader.GetString(3), sql_reader.GetString(4), sql_reader.GetString(5), sql_reader.GetInt16(6), sql_reader.GetInt16(7), sql_reader.GetString(8), sql_reader.GetString(9));
                        break;
                }//end switch

            }
            sql_reader.Close();
            sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();
        }
        sql_connection.Close();

    }

}
```

I am using a webform to output the data, was debugging and researching the net, but could not find a solution.

Here is the orders class:
    public class Orders : I_Orders {
        protected static string edition;
        protected static string rarity;
        protected static uint id;
        protected static string name;
        protected static string type;
        protected static string affilations;
        protected static int points;
        private static int span;
        protected static string requirements;
        protected static string specials;

```
    internal Orders (){
        edition = "none";
        rarity = "";
        id = 0;
        name = "";
        type = "";
        affilations = "";
        points = 0;
        span = 0;
        requirements = "";
        specials = "";
    }
    public void modify(string edi, string rar, uint i_d, string nam, string typ, string aff, int poi, int spa, string requ, string spec) {
        edition = edi;
        rarity = rar;
        id = i_d;
        name = nam;
        type = typ;
        affilations = aff;
        points = poi;
        span = spa;
        requirements = requ;
        specials = spec;
    }

    public string get_edition() { return edition; }
    public string get_rarity() { return rarity; }
    public uint get_id() { return id; }
    public string get_name() { return name; }
    public string get_type() { return type; }
    public string get_affilations() { return affilations; }
    public int get_points() { return points; }
    public int get_span() { return span; }
    public string get_requirements() { return requirements; }
    public string get_specials() { return specials; }
}
```

I need to access the orders-objects in the entire project. Can you give me global alternatives?

I am using the switch statements, because the sql-statement is changing 6 times and to modifying the orders only once.

**EDIT**

I implemented IDisposable Interface and using my objects in the class Assignments. But still got the same attributes, even if I modify objects (for testing purposes) in my webform without calling the assignment method.

Comment: Please show us the code for the unconventionally-named `objects` class. Also note that global state like this is a *really* bad idea, particularly in a web context... and that all your variable names are *also* unconventional, and you're not disposing of any of your resources properly.

Comment: That's what you are doing - repeating the same query six times, each time writing all rows one by one over the same global instance, the one pointed to by `i`, which is *not* related to the order of the results. This code has too many issues - the globals, the iterations, concatenating statements ...

Comment: This code makes no sense. Why don't you simply select all records that have IDs in the range you want?

Comment: I randomly select 6 ids of over 50. That's left in my posting, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Orders class fields were static, therefore there was only one copy of the instance possible.

Only use static members if you need only one copy of them.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could fix it with removing the `Queue<int> assign_ids;`.
Change

```
Convert.ToString(assign_ids.Peek())
```

outside the loop:

```
id_string = "1"
```

inside the loop:

```
id_string = i.ToString()
```

As a side note, you should pay attention to IDisposable handling, code structure and command parameters handling.
Disposable objects are best handled with using statement.
You should avoid code duplication (you are duplicating command execution code inside and outside the loop).
Avoid string concatenation, which is a subject to sql injection and performance issues with sql query plan caches. Learn about using parameters with sql commands.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the main problem still exists. All the members of a instance is having the same attributes. I randomly select 6 ids of over 50. That's left in my posting, sorry for that